# CoreData relationship _NSFaultingMutableSet get data

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I have a managed object that has a to-many relationship with more objects of the same type as itself. I'm accessing these objects using `valueForKey:` and passing the name of the relationship.

If I log out the return value I get a list of the related objects and if log out the class name I get: `_NSFaultingMutableSet`.

As I understand it a Core Data fault is a placeholder for a genuine `NSManagedObject` and the real object is only retrieved if and when data on it is accessed.

The problem is if I try to iterate the set, or call `allObjects` and try to iterate the resulting array I get nothing. The `count` property is always 0.

Here is the original offending code:

```
NSArray *UUIDs = [[(NSSet *)[managedObject valueForKey:@"..."] allObjects] rh_map:^id (id entity) {
    // This section is never called because allObjects returns an empty array
    return [NSUUID UUIDWithData:[entity valueForKey:@"uuid"]]
}];
[self setValue:UUIDs forKeyPath:@"UUIDs"];
```

What am I supposed to do to get core data to fetch the data correctly, and access the real object?